# stuck with (last) partial integration step for $\int x^2 e^{2x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am stuck with this integral in the last step of partial integration:
\begin{align}
\int x^2 e^{2x}\,dx & = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x^2-\int \frac{1}{2}e^{2x} 2x \,dx \\[6pt]
& = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x^2-\int e^{2x} x \, dx \\[6pt]
& = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x^2-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x-\int \frac{1}{2}e^{2x} \,dx\\[6pt]
& = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x^2-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}x- \frac{1}{2} \int e^{2x} \,dx
\end{align}
I have problems with evalautating the final integral, especially with the factoring of constants (the $\frac{1}{2}$ for the integral. The solution for the last integral is 
$+\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}$, but it seems I have a knot in my brain and can't get the last step right, because I would solve it to $-\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}$...
How does the last step evaluate to positive?

Comment: You forget one minus in your second integration by parts (this means that the integral on the third line has wrong sign). Also, there is an $x$ too much inside the integral on the third row, it should be differentiated.

Comment: I just see the x too much is a typing error.
Edit:// But where did I miss the minus?
the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ and the $2$ in the integral can be canceled

Comment: $a-(b-c)=a-b+c$, not $a-b-c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using integration by parts on $\int x^2 e^{2x} dx$, we let $u=x^2$ and $dv=e^{2x}dx$.  So, that $du=2xdx$ and $v=\frac12 e^{2x}$. Thus,

$$\int x^2 e^{2x} dx = \frac12 x^2e^{2x}- \int xe^{2x}dx$$

For the integral $\int xe^{2x}dx$, we integrate by parts again.  To that end, let $u=x$ and $dv=e^{2x}dx$ so that $du=dx$ and $v=\frac12 e^{2x}$.   Then,

$$\int xe^{2x}dx=\frac12 x e^{2x}-\frac12 \int e^{2x}dx$$

using $\int e^{2x}dx = \frac12 e^{2x}+C$ where $C$ is an integration constant, we have

$$\begin{align} 
\int x^2 e^{2x} dx & =\frac12 x^2e^{2x}- \int xe^{2x}dx\\
& =\frac12 x^2e^{2x}-\left(\frac12 xe^{2x}-\frac14 e^{2x}\right)+C \\
& =\frac12 x^2e^{2x}-\frac12 xe^{2x}+\frac14 e^{2x}+C 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Uhm, that is clear to me, I was refering to the $\frac{1}{2}$ which I can factor out and put them in front of the integral, there I get stuck with evaluating

Comment: I added the entire development and really want to help here.  Let me know if this suffices as I want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Okay, I have the $-\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the integral, and I now that the last integral evaluates at $\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$ 
My problem is: Why is the $\frac{1}{4}$ positive?

Comment: A negative times a negative.  Check out the two integration by parts.  In the first, there is an integral with a negative sign.  In the second, the second term again has a negative sign.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I still don't get it:
Step 2 to step3, I used the partial integral rule: $F*G-\int F*G'$ and I see the result in step 2. So I only need to integrate the last integrand, clear which evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$. But when I  multiply it with the term in front of the integral it gets negative. Or is there another $-$ in front of the integral I don't get?

Comment: That's OK.  I added another line.  Better?

Comment: Ah, I think it's clear to me now, I see it, the $-$ is not only for the fraction but for the whole following term!
I first was confused with it and seemed to have a knot in my brain ;)

Comment: Glad I could help!  And best wishes in your math endeavors going forward.  Minus signs plague all of us.

Answer (score 1):

If it's easier for you, you could find the same result via differentiation under the integral sign.  Here's how:

First notice that $\partial_\beta e^{\beta x} = xe^{\beta x}$ and $\partial_\beta \partial_\beta e^{\beta x} = x^2e^{\beta x}$.  Then we have:

$$\begin{align}\int x^2 e^{\beta x}\,dx &= \int \partial_\beta \partial_\beta e^{\beta x}\,dx \\ &= \partial_\beta \partial_\beta \int e^{\beta x}\,dx \\ &= \partial_\beta \partial_\beta \frac {e^{\beta x}}{\beta} + C \\ &= \partial_\beta \frac{\beta xe^{\beta x}-e^{\beta x}}{\beta^2} + C \\ &= \frac{(xe^{\beta x}+\beta x^2 e^{\beta x}-x e^{\beta x})\beta^2-2\beta(\beta xe^{\beta x} -e^{\beta x})}{\beta^4} + C\end{align}$$

Now, let $\beta = 2$ and simplify.

Notice: I know that last expression looks pretty complex, but it was obtained with just the quotient rule, product rule, and chain rule -- so it's pretty straightforward.  In fact, this highlights what differentiation under the integral sign does for you -- it turns an integral that would normally take several steps (sometimes several very difficult steps) into an *easy* integral and then a differentiation that takes several steps.  But derivatives are usually easier than integrals so that's not such a bad thing.

Comment: Never seen this way before, for me it's more straightforward with partial integration rule and/or substitution rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can evaluate $$\int x^2 e^{2x}\, dx $$ by identfying $$y= e^{-2x}\int x^2 e^{2x}\, dx$$ as a particular solution of the differential equation $$y' + 2y = x^2. \tag 1$$  and look for a solution of the form $$y = ax^2 + bx + c, \quad y'= 2ax + b  $$ subbing in $(1)$ and equation the coefficients we get $$2ax + b + 2(ax^2 + b x + c) = x^2\to a = \frac 12, b = -\frac 12, c = \frac 14.$$ therefore 
$$\int x^2 e^{2x}\, dx  = \left(\frac 12 x^2 - \frac 12 x + \frac 14\right)e^{2x} + C$$